# How to write file from google sheet using next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js

am stuck with a problem, can anyone tell me how can I write file from google sheet using next JS , read operation is performed fine, I facing problem in write Operation, Please tell me what should I do? If you have any query please free feel to ask any time

> sheet.js

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function getDataFromSheets() {
  try {

    const target = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
      process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      null,
      (process.env.GOOGLE_SHEETS_PRIVATE_KEY || '').replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      target
    );

    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: jwt });
    const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID,
      range: 'sheet'
    });

    
    const rows = response.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      return rows.map((row) => ({
        title: row[0],
        description: row[1],
      }));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return [];
}
```

> index.js

This  is my index.js file here you have to write your output display code

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

import { getDataFromSheets } from './libs/sheets'

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Nextsheet </title>
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Welcome to Nextsheet </h1>
        <p>Connecting NextJS with Google Spreadsheets as Database</p>
        <ul>
          {data && data.length ? (
            data.map((item) => (
              <li key={item}>
                {item.title} - {item.description}
              </li>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>Error: do not forget to setup your env variables </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const sheet = await getDataFromSheets();

  return {
    props: {
      data: sheet.slice(0, sheet.length), // remove sheet header
    },
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is not working as expected?

Comment: How to write code in write file from google sheet

Comment: So are you receiving any errors when making the request? Which part of your code is not working as expected?

Comment: https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/nodejs-write-data-in-a-google-sheet/   here is the example of write file in node js but i want to apply in next js